# Audio Streaming using Document Dictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-streaming

As I am beginner with iOS, I did not found any suitable code for my understanding over tutorials, I just want to access an audio from my desktop using document dictionary behind a button. Can anyone please help me out!

Comment: Just add your that audio file in your xcode project

Comment: Done this and it works, Thanks @kb920